# Does anybody know how to generate a grid in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Instead of having a 2D list like:

`[[1,2],[3,4]]`

I was wondering if there is any way that you can have:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

Or something in the similar manner where there is a hard enter between rows and I can refer to an element in the list as index i and j?

Comment: Do you want the new-line when printed? `string = intercalate "\n" . map show $ list` achieves that. (Also, `list !! i !! j` works perfectly well for indexing the `i,j`th element.)

Comment: `"[1, 2]<enter>[3, 4]"` Is *one* string representation of the list `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, another string representation is `"[[1, 2], [3, 4]]"`. But still, they represent the same value.

Comment: If you want the newline in your source code, it's OK, but you still need the comma in the middle and the `[` and `]` at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but if you're currently doing

```
print grid
```

try replacing it with

```
mapM_ print grid
```

to print each row separately.