# Haskell - Printing grid

Tags: function, haskell, printing, grid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anybody know how to generate a grid in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772599/does-anybody-know-how-to-generate-a-grid-in-haskell)

I was wondering if there was a function in Haskell, that allows you to go from a list of lists, such as [[1,2],[3,4]] to something more readable like:

[[1,2]

[3,4]]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unlines` function to get a single string from a list of lines. You can get a list of strings from a `[[Int]]` using `map show`. You can print this to the screen with `putStr`. Together, you get:

```
putStr . unlines $ map show [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

which prints:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

Comment: For direct printing, you can use the shorter mapM_ print [[1, 2], [3, 4]] .